# How to fetch original reset_password_token from hashed token in devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

In Devise, raw and hashed token pair are generated by the below code

```
raw_token, hashed_token = Devise.token_generator.generate(self.class, :reset_password_token)
```

You can get hashed token by raw token, per below code

```
hashed_token = Devise.token_generator.digest(self, :reset_password_token, raw_token)
```

Is there a way to reverse it, by hashed token, can I know what is the original raw token?

I suspect that raw token was filtered/changed when email sent via sendgrid, which changes to url click-tracking links.

Comment: hash-ing is a one-way process, you cannot reverse it, that is the whole point of hashing in general.